# jQuery show() function is not executed in Safari if submit handler returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, forms

Ok, I've bound a submit event handler to a form. The handler is set up to validate data, then after validation passes disable further form submittal, as well as display a 'Please wait ... processing' message.

Here's the basic structure:

```
function handler() {
    // Validation stuff goes here.
    ...
    // Validation passes, show message and return true.
    $('#processing-msg').show();  // Show the 'processing' message.
    $form.bind('submit', function() { return false }); // Disable further form submits.
    return true;  // Proceed with form submittal.
}
```

Up until the very last `return` statement, if I break before `return true`, the processing message will show. But if I allow it to `return true` the message doesn't show up at all, ever. Also the submit button won't appear disabled (another part of the process). This works in pretty much every browser except Safari. I've tried commenting out the submit-disable logic, but no dice.

#### Update

I haven't been able to completely re-create the issue on jsfiddle. But here you can see how the order of functions called differs in Safari (`alerts()` happen before message is displayed): http://jsfiddle.net/skttw/3/

Comment: What is the version of your Safari? http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle test for your code? i'm not sure what you doing but i had some similar looking problem with chrome(same webkit as safari)/firefox before

Comment: Must be some other conflict, the fiddle works as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/skttw/2/

Comment: If this helps, if I sandwich the `$.show()` call between alerts, the alerts happen, but the show doesn't. Only if I return false... *scratching my head*

Comment: Here we go, there is something quirky with the order in which things are done: http://jsfiddle.net/skttw/3/ Notice that 'hidden' doesn't show up until after second alert.

Comment: I just tried the fiddle on Safari 6.0.2 and the "I'm hidden!" text appeared right after the "here" alert or, in other words, right *before* the "andhere" alert. You say it doesn't show up until *after* the "andhere" alert?

Comment: Yep! It doesn't show up until after 'andhere' alert. I will try a Safari upgrade and see.

Comment: Just upgraded to 6.0.2, same problem. Now *that* is weird.

Comment: @BrianDuncan Interesting. Which OS are you running? I'm on Mac OS 10.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking this question led to the answer: [JavaScript commands not executed in order in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166459/javascript-commands-not-executed-in-order-in-safari)

Apparently Safari renders changes to the HTML according to its internal tics. So all of the functions called *are* being executed in order, but are not necessarily *rendered* yet.

Also, rendering is halted during the execution of certain functions, `alert()` being one of them, and in my case, the `onsubmit` event! That was why I was seeing the out-of-order looking results.

So I ended up using a bit of dirtiness:

```
            var show = function() { $('#processing_msg').show() };
            setTimeout(show,0);
```